Dynamic float/other arrays in expl3
I wish to make my float array dynamic in the way I first compute the number of elements and then I declare e.g.
\fparray_new:Nn \l_effort_per_month_fpa { \g_num_months_int }

I still probably do not fully understand the scope model of global/local variables. Does just naming variable l_ or g_ somehow change its scope?
Do I get it correctly, that before I first use variable I need to declare it. Once variable is declared by e.g. \new_int I can never redeclare it. And even if I declare it in function and call that function twice then the runtime complain about double declaration even if the variable start l_.
So how to declare dynamic arrays in the situation I don't want to explicitly hardcode its size?  Shall I create special function e.g.
\int_new:N \l_size_int
\cs_new_protected:Nn \initialize_float_array:n {
\int_set:Nx \l_size_int {#1}
\fparray_new:Nn \l_effort_per_month_fpa {\l_size_int}
}

And then use it once I set e.g. \g_num_months_int calling
\initialize_float_array:n {\g_num_months_int}
Do I still miss something about the scoping? It is for me unnatural to declare variable inside function with such global scope. I am not sure if this variable \l_effort_per_month_fpa will be visible from other functions?
Maybe to further clarify the intention of this machinery. I want \l_effort_per_month_fpa be an array used in particular data structure to be used in one sty/tex file. But the value of \g_num_months_int is computed in another sty/tex file and I need to declare this array just after I have this number available. Even if I could theoretically do  \fparray_new:Nn \l_effort_per_month_fpa {\g_num_months_int } when \g_num_months_int  is set, it is for me visually more compelling having the variable, which I will use for purposes of single function in my code declared somehow close to that function. It is hard to have used to the fact, that all variables are global and it is not too much expressed in the documentation in favor of declarative locality or globality that has nothing to do with real scope with those variables.

It is not clear what your question is and you only provide a fragment of code, but macro (functions) in tex do not have local variables there is no scope implied by a function call, local and global scope always refers to tex groups that have been explicitly added not to the replacement text of function definitions which have no implied scope.

\fparray_new:Nn \l_size_int is wrong as the variable should be global, see the documentation of \fparray_new:Nn in interface3.pdf, you are also missing the second argument

The posted code produces ! Argument of \__cs_generate_from_signature:nnNNNn has an extra }.

Sorry I will focus more next time. But the answer is scope of all variables is global from their declaration to the end of documents. Their values can sometimes be local. Float arrays can not be resized and need to be declared just once.

I am just trying to deal with the fact, that I can not declare any variables in functions, which I wish to use multiple times but I can use even undeclared variables,, which will be available at the time of actual function call.

The body of a function definition is not consulted at all at the point of definition, so naturally you can use undefined commands you can declare variables multiple times or do anything else, it will only be an error if those things are an error at the point you use the function, if you use it. There is nothing special about expl3 here, that is just how tex (and macro languages in general) work.

That was maybe my misconception that I was thinking expl3 layer will make it more like procedural language with proper scoping.

expl3 is written in tex, so it can not change tex. It has proper, documented scoping, it is just different to what you expect, but you would get similar misconceptions if you wrote fortran assuming it was like C++ or java assuming it was like Fortran. All these things are language specific.

My understanding (and I expect someone will correct me if I am wrong) is that all variables are global, and the l_ or g_ is by convention. Also that using gset on l_ variables (and the other way around) causes more swapping/stacking/memory use/problems (I don't remember at this time which, but I do recall seeing it in one of the docs, probably interface3.pdf).

Note, also, that "variable" is not quite the same concept as other programming languages - you can put a "function, which takes arguments" into l_mymodule_list_of_parts_tl and it will work (but confuse anyone expecting a local token list). From my perspective, comparing expl3 to a functional programming language (rather than a procedural programming language) worked better for my understanding of how to best use and understand it.

\fparray_new:Nn \l_effort_per_month_fpa \g_num_months_int

is incorrect the documentation of \fparray_new:Nn  explicitly states that the first argument (the array) should be a global variable named g_... as all array assignments are global. As the second argument is n it should be a {...} group. While it's (usually) possible to omit the braces if the argument is a single token it is not good style.
This size argument could be a global or local variable, or literal integer depending on the intended use, so one of
\fparray_new:Nn \g_effort_per_month_fpa {\g_num_months_int}
\fparray_new:Nn \g_effort_per_month_fpa {\l_num_months_int}
\fparray_new:Nn \g_effort_per_month_fpa {10}

It's hard to guess the intention of
\fparray_new:Nn \l_size_int

Perhaps declaring a local integer variable so
\int_new:N \l_size_int

(although \l_size_int would be badly named it is missing a unique prefix for your module name.)

In your edited version you added
\int_set:Nx \l_size_int {#1}

and asked

I am not sure if this variable \l_effort_per_month_fpa will be visible from other functions?

the question isn't clear, I assume you meant to ask if the variable \l_size_int  would be visible from elsewhere, the value set would be visible anywhere in the local scope (ie the current tex group such as a latex environment) command definitions are unrelated to scoping, a command is always equivalent to its replacement text, and implies no scope of any kind.

I edited the question so I show the intention of the code and intended meaning of  \l_size_int variable.  Thank you for raising those points!

@VojtaK you still have not provided an example that can be run, just fragments of code where you expect people to guess what declarations to add. I think my answer though still applies to your edited version \fparray_new:Nn clearly defines an fparray and requires two arguments (N and n) and you only supplied it one argument so get the error I describe.

@VojtaK I added a note to the answer but if you had supplied a proper test case and tested the code before posting the question it would be a lot easier to answer
